# PHP how do i write a multi dimmensional array into file

Tags: php

I am trying to use files to hold an array for checkers

this is the array

```
$board = array(
         array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
         array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
         array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
         array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
         array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
         array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
         array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
         array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
         array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
   );
```

while also giving the values so that i can set the beginning of the board with the pieces placed in a predefined positions to start the game in then have them user input which location they want to move the pieces into

I already have this while loop

```
      $row = 0;
    print "<form>";
    print "<table border = 1>";
    while ($row < 8){ // Counts to 8. (from 0...7 = 8 times. 0 ... 8 = 9 times)
       print "<tr>";
       $row++;
       $col = 0; // reset column to 0 each time printing one row.

       while ($col < 8){
        print "<td>";
        if($Board[$row][$col] == 0)
        {
            $value=$row.$col;
            print "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"box[]\" value=\"$value\">";
            // Add \ before " otherwise it will treat as the end of the quote.

        }
        print "</td>";
        $col++;

       }

       print "</tr>";

    }
    print "</table>";
    print "</form>";
```

}

Comment: what I am trying to find out is what php functions do i need to make this array store in the file then display board into html tables with 8x8 rows and columns.

Comment: I just want to be pointed in the right direction and I don't expect anyone to this for me

Answer (score 10):

```
file_put_contents($f, serialize($board));
```

this will serialize your multidimensional array in a file.

To read it back, use

```
$board = unserialize(file_get_contents($f));
```

Answer (score 4):

2 variants:
using serialize

```
#dump:
file_put_contents('file_name', serialize($board));
#restore:
$board=unserialize(file_get_contents('file_name'));
```

using JSON:

```
#dump:
file_put_contents('file_name', json_encode($board));
#restore:
$board=json_decode(file_get_contents('file_name'));
```

JSON variant works faster, but can dump only simple structures (strings, arrays, numbers). serialize can dump objects too but works slower and generate more output

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation, so why would it not be able to dump objects?

Comment: @BoltClock: not of specific classes you get back after decoding, only `stdClass`, which may not be what you want...

Comment: @Wrikken - "not of specific classes you get back after decoding, only stdClass, which may not be what you want" what did you mean by this comment towards @BoltClock about JSON

Comment: That:`class Foo{}; echo get_class(json_decode(json_encode(new Foo())));` results in `stdClass` and not in `Foo` (in other words: the type of object is not preserved in JSON (it's just not in the JSON spec).

Comment: so using JSON on this example isn't good or is it I have never used it before

Comment: using JSON in this example is good, because you use simple arrays, not PHP objects. So, json will work OK for you (and use JSON is preferable, because it work faster + JSON dumps are much more human-readable + JSON dumps can be used in many different programming languages)

Comment: I am using this to make a php checkers  display board and pieces but how do i add values to the board so i can add pieces and position values do i do this when I $board=json_decode(file_get_contents('file_name'));  read back with json decode or do i put the values when i dump the array into file

Answer (score 1):

why don't you serialize the array and store it as a string into the file. to get the array back, you can read the string from the file and un-serialize it. have a read here [here](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Answer (score 0):

Why serialize and store ? Even you can directly print array to file

ob_start();

print_r( $yourArry);

$output = ob_get_clean();

file_put_contents( 'yourfilename.txt',$output );

See example here http://www.my-php-scripts.net/index.php/Array-Scripts/php-write-multidimensional-array-into-file-advanced-php.html